# GDAL tools creating artefacts

Tags: gdal, convert, mosaic

I am running the following line in a bash script:

`gdal_translate -of JP2KAK ${2}.vrt ${2}.jp2`

to convert a virtual mosaic created with `gdalbuildvrt` to a JP2 file of the same name. The command produces the output with the artefact shown in the attached image. I have also tried using different `QUALITY=n` settings with the same result.  Creating a GeoTIFF from the same virtual mosaic works fine with no artefact.

Can anyone explain why the JP2KAK driver is causing the artefact shown in the attached image?

[image: output showing artefact]

Comment: I would say that without test data nobody can explain the artefact. Even with test data only few people could have a try because most GDAL users do not have Kakadu license and driver. What happens if you convert the GeoTIFF into JPEG 2000 with the KDU driver?